# How are differences in primitive types expressed during memory complexity evaluation?

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity

### Contents

1. Question Statement
2. Elaboration and Examples
3. Resources Visited
4. Answers (As they are posted)
5. Follow-up Questions (As they are conceived)

---

### Question

How is the size of a primitive type considered when calculating the big-O style notation for 'space(memory) complexity'?

### Elaboration and Examples

If I allocate an array N elements in length, and each element is a 32-bit integer, I have presumably allocated approximately N*32 bits. It is my understanding that the memory complexity of this allocation is considered O(N).

Using the above example, if I treat each element in the array as a pointer to a unique linked list, wherein the linked list is of length 1 (contains 1 node and a null pointer) and the data segment of that node is also a 32-bit integer, I am clearly now allocating:

1. 32-bit array element
2. 32-bit linked list data
3. 32-bit linked list null pointer

Has my array become O(3*32*N)? I understand that this would still be considered O(N), but as you can see knowing the difference is relevant in cases where a time/memory tradeoff becomes relevant (e.g. I can use linked lists of various lengths with head pointers stored in the elements of the array to delay the point at which I must dynamically resize the array, since I can merely lengthen the linked lists - this amortizes the insert operation to O(1), but increases the memory complexity substantially until the resizing actually happens, wherein the linked lists would revert to elements in the array, and thus consume substantially less memory)

### Resources already visited:

related questions on Stack Overflow:

[Effect of memory usage in the complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371480/effect-of-memory-usage-in-the-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

[Why is the complexity of A* exponential in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715401/why-is-the-complexity-of-a-exponential-in-memory)

And wikibooks had the following to say:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Asymptotic_Notation

Additionally, wikipedia expounded regarding this topic in substantial detail:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

### Answers

### Follow-up Questions

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of big-O notation is that we don't ever have something like `O(32*N)`.  If the difference is really important, then the accepted convention is to not use big-O notation or to say something like `32*O(N)`.

Comment: and you never consider non-portable factors when big-O notation is present.

Comment: so the width of an integer type is never taken into account when writing big-O notation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion stems from a misunderstanding about big-O notation. If you have an array of 32-bit ints, it definitely takes up less space than an array of pointers to singleton linked lists holding 32-bit integers (probably by a factor of 3 or 4, depending on what kind of linked list you have). However, asympotically speaking, both of these setups require Θ(n) memory, since Θ notation talks about the asymptotic growth rate of the memory consumption and both approaches require memory linearly proportional to the number of elements being used.

Typically, asymptotic space complexity is used to rank different approaches against one another when the space usage is different. For example, one data structure with space complexity Θ(n log n) will in the long run always use more space than a data structure with space complexity Θ(n). However, two different data structures with space complexity Θ(n) might have wildly different memory footprints. As an example, consider difference in space complexity between a standard dynamic array and a Fibonacci heap. Both require Θ(n) memory, but the actual memory needed is hugely different (the Fibonacci heap probably needs 8 - 12x more memory).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you; I was expecting this was the answer I would receive, but I suppose although I could sit down at a table and discuss the intricacies of the average/worst case memory complexity of a data structure, I am having trouble finding a tool that expresses this information with finer granularity - I mean, the ambiguity is great for theorizing, but when I need to actually design and implement something where an order of magnitude is extremely significant, regardless of its proportion to N, I find this notation to be suffocating.

Comment: I suppose in retrospect what I'm trying to ask here is "if we do analysis using big-O, and arrive at two "big-O equivalent" data structures, clearly there's a point where we say something like "except this one is 3x larger than the other" otherwise our analyses are a bit half-assed. The curiosity is that there is no analytical process that actually acknowledges that point where we decide the 3x space complexity of one DS is a tradeoff we're unwilling to make.